# writing to SQLite while proceeding with application process

Tags: swift

I would like to write a list of restaurants to my app so I don't have to do pagination when I filter alphabetically. However, since there are like 2000 records, my application will freeze for approximately 10 seconds before the user can do anything else.
Currently this is in AppDelegate.swift

```
db["restaurants"].insert(Expression<String?>("id") <- String(item["id"]!!.intValue), Expression<String?>("thumbnail") <- thumbnailUrl, Expression<String?>("name") <- (item["name"] as? String), Expression<String?>("cuisine") <- (item["cuisine"] as? String), Expression<String?>("city") <- (item["city"] as? String))
```

Is there any way I can let the user proceed with logging in etc while I write all the restaurant entries in AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

Comment: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
            // do whatever
        }

Comment: Could you check my comment in the 1st answer?

Comment: feel free to open up a new question and post the relevant code there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dispatch` to do it while user is doing something else

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // whatever
});
```

Comment: It works, now a followed up problem, if a user purposely skip everything and go to the alphabetical listing. My program will crash with the problem: "database is locked."
Is there any way to check the status of this? I'm using https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift

Comment: @Happiehappie is you db empty that time? did you debug it? Maybe it relates to unwrapping of some value?